# Ubuntu 22.04 does not boot. Hardware or software issue?

Tags: boot, ssd, acpi

Some days ago I shutdown my Ubuntu 22.04 properly. When I powered it up the day after, I found this error message:

[image]

At first I tried to inspect the logs as suggested but honestly it was hard to read through the very long file, and also I cannot copy and paste it here.
Then I issued `Control+D` to continue and it gave the error in red.

I suspected the SSD might be corrupted (even it's quite new). So I ran a live Ubuntu system and did an `fsck` on all the partitions. It completed the check successfully and probably it repaired something because the next reboot was fine and I landed to the Ubuntu installation.

From the Disks utility I ran the SMART Data and Tests. Also this one was completed without any error and the indication was "Disk is OK".
After a couple of days of normal use, I'm stuck again in the first error.
Doing the same procedure is not enough to recover the boot. Here the output from the live os when checking the root partition:

[image]

For two days and dozen of trials I was not able to start my machine anymore.
Anyway, it seems to me it reach the last step before launching the graphical environment. In fact, I can login and see all the files.

I was tempted to reinstall it (i.e. `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`) but the last boot was successfully. Now I'm really confused.

Last bit of information. No matter which kind of o.s. I boot (the installed one or a live one) now I get these messages just after POST:

[image]

I've never seen them and a Google search led me to generic stuff, I didn't find an exact match for the cause of these errors.

Some hw info:

```
MSI Z77A-G45 (MS-7752)
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
4x DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0,8 ns) 4 GB each
GK104 [GeForce GTX 670] using `nvidia-driver-470` from `metapackage`
```

With this information, are you able to put me on the right track?
I need to deeper test the SSD or there something odd in the X environment that I can easily fix reinstalling some packages?

### UPDATE

This morning it does not boot again. Definitely something is odd here.